# JObject.Parse key/value with json.net in C#

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, json.net

Hey all I have the following code:

```
try {
  foreach (var x1 in JObject.Parse(json1)) {
     string name = x1.Key;
     JToken value = x1.Value;
```

There are no visible errors with the above code. However, once I run the application and it gets to that point it errors and says:

> 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'Key'

So whats going on here. My VB.net code works like the above:

```
Try
    For Each x1 In JObject.Parse(json1)
       Dim name As String = x1.Key
       Dim value As JToken = x1.Value
```

Comment: Not sure why VB would work, nor why the compiler wouldn't catch it (unless that setup uses `dynamic`), but I believe the property you're looking for is [actually `Name`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty_Name.htm).

Answer (score 1):

`JProperty` (you get JPropertys by iterating over a JObject) inherits from `JContainer`, which inherits from [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm). `JToken` implements [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This makes it essentially a `dynamic` object, which allows you to access anything on it at compile time. That's why you dont get a compiler error.

At runtime the [DLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) discovers that there is no `Key` property on `x1` and throws that exception.

If you want to get the property name, you should use the `Name` property.

```
foreach (var x1 in JObject.Parse(json1)) {
    string name = x1.Name;
    JToken value = x1.Value;
```